# Python | Regex | Split Rows; Not columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

I have a dataframe with 5 nested rows (all containing the following data)

```
1ItWB (NL)$327,481,7484,148$123,403,4194,1039/8/172The
ExorcistWB$232,906,145-n/a-12/26/733Get
OutUni.$176,040,6653,143$33,377,0602,7812/24/174The Blair Witch
ProjectArt.$140,539,0992,538$1,512,054277/16/995The ConjuringWB
(NL)$137,400,1413,115$41,855,3262,9037/19/136Paranormal
ActivityPar.$107,918,8102,712$77,873129/25/097Interview with the
VampireWB$105,264,6082,604$36,389,7052,60411/11/94
```

What I want to do is split into new rows; not columns.

I have tried something like this:

```
df["Box_Office"].str.split(r'([\d][A-Z][a-z]*)', expand=True)
df["Box_Office"].str.split(r'([\d][A-Z][a-z]*)', expand=True).melt()
df["Box_Office"].str.split(r'([\d][A-Z][a-z]*)', expand=True).stack().to_frame()
```

The regex is splitting at each new rank (EG: 2The, 3Get, 4The). I just want the split to create new rows, not columns. The Regex needs some work, but I'm happy to work through that on my own.

I can **melt** the dataframe to create rows, but then cleaning becomes time-consuming (happy to go down that path if there is no other way).

**Stacking** is closer, but it's splitting into seperate rows (which naturally has to do with my regex). This feels the closest, but I can't find a regex pattern to capture this [yet].

The ideal outcome is below but all I really need is the Title and the Gross

```
Rank      Title         Studio      Gross         Theatres       Date
1         IT            WB          $327,481,748  4,138          9/8/17
2         The Exorcist  WB          $232,906,145  NA             12/26/73
```

This following gets a little closer

```
df["Box_Office"].str.split(r'(\$[0-9,/]*)', expand=True).stack().to_frame()
```

[image]

**Does extract or split work with expanding down across rows, and not across columns?**

Comment: Arrgghh, you have a bad approach! Your data come from a website (probably http://www.boxofficemojo.com). Use an html parser (beautifulsoup) to extract the already structured informations. Use the html structure instead of trying to split a concatened text with regex.

Comment: Hello - I used BeautifulSoup to get this data - this is the structure returned. I can send my code if it will help?

Comment: ok, instead of extracting the text content for each tr tag (that concatenates all text nodes), loop over the td tags to obtain each information separately for each tr tag.

Comment: Off course you can put additional informations into your question. However, take care to only post the interesting part of your code (not all your code if it is long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
(?P<title>[A-Z](?:(?!WB|Par|Art|Uni)[-\sA-Za-z])+)
(?P<studio>WB|Par|Art|Uni)
[^$]*
(?P<gross>\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*)
(?P<theatres>(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*)|-n/a-)
[$,\d]*?
(?P<date>(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])/\d{1,2}/\d{2})
```

---

Which in `Python` would be:

```
import pandas as pd, re

junk = """
1ItWB (NL)$327,481,7484,148$123,403,4194,1039/8/172The
ExorcistWB$232,906,145-n/a-12/26/733Get
OutUni.$176,040,6653,143$33,377,0602,7812/24/174The Blair Witch
ProjectArt.$140,539,0992,538$1,512,054277/16/995The ConjuringWB
(NL)$137,400,1413,115$41,855,3262,9037/19/136Paranormal
ActivityPar.$107,918,8102,712$77,873129/25/097Interview with the
VampireWB$105,264,6082,604$36,389,7052,60411/11/94"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
(?P<Title>[A-Z](?:(?!WB|Par|Art|Uni)[-\sA-Za-z])+)
(?P<Studio>WB|Par|Art|Uni)
[^$]*
(?P<Gross>\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*)
(?P<Theatres>(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*)|-n/a-)
[$,\d]*?
(?P<Date>(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])/\d{1,2}/\d{2})''', re.VERBOSE)

def replacer(d):
    d['Title'] = d['Title'].replace('\n', ' ')
    return d

records = (replacer(m.groupdict()) for m in rx.finditer(junk))
df = pd.DataFrame(records)

# reorder the columns if necessary
df = df[['Title', 'Studio', 'Gross', 'Theatres', 'Date']]
print(df)
```

---

This yields

```
                        Title Studio         Gross Theatres      Date
0                          It     WB  $327,481,748    4,148    9/8/17
1                The Exorcist     WB  $232,906,145    -n/a-  12/26/73
2                     Get Out    Uni  $176,040,665    3,143  12/24/17
3     The Blair Witch Project    Art  $140,539,099    2,538   7/16/99
4               The Conjuring     WB  $137,400,141    3,115   7/19/13
5         Paranormal Activity    Par  $107,918,810    2,712   9/25/09
6  Interview with the Vampire     WB  $105,264,608    2,604  11/11/94
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vKMTAb/4/).

---

As for your original question: you could extract columns and then transpose the dataframe (like turn it around). However, wherefrom do you get this data in the first place? Scraped from somehwere? You might want to rethink this step!

Comment: There is something wrong with the date of the film "Get Out". The date should be "2/24/17", but comes out "12/24/17". Also missed the film "The Blair Witch Project". I propose [another regex](https://regex101.com/r/opkWY7/4).

Comment: This worked (really nice regex - too) - learned a lot just from this. Assuming 'verbose' allows for cleaner code and ignored whitespace? This is really handy. I did have one question - what is this code actually doing '(replacer(m.groupdict()) for m in rx.finditer(junk))' - is it just a list comprehension iterating through the text? Not sure what the groupdict or finditer variables are doing - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AndreiOdegov: There is clearly `12/24/17` and `The Blai Witch Project` (3).

Comment: @Jan, sorry for the record  with id 3. But the record with id 2 contains `$33,377,060;2,781;2/24/17`. Right?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov: That is true, the whole expression is ambiguous when it comes to the date part and I would change the scraping mechanism in the first place!